# RuntimeError: size mismatch, m1: [4 x 3136], m2: [64 x 5] at c:\a\w\1\s\tmp_conda_3.7_1

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, computer-vision, pytorch, resnet

I used  python 3 and when i insert  transform random crop size 224 it gives miss match error.

[here my code](https://github.com/kajasumanie/medical-plant-classification/blob/master/imageclassifier)

what did i wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code makes variations on [resnet](https://pytorch.org/docs/0.4.1/torchvision/models.html#id3): you changed the number of channels, the number of bottlenecks at each "level", and you removed a "level" entirely. As a result, the dimension of the feature map you have at the end of `layer3` is **not** 64: you have a larger spatial dimension than you anticipated by the [`nn.AvgPool2d(8)`](https://github.com/kajasumanie/medical-plant-classification/blob/master/imageclassifier#L103). The error message you got actually tells you that the output of `level3` is of shape `64`x`56`x`56` and after avg pooling with kernel and stride 8 you have `64`x`7`x`7`=`3136` dimensional feature vector, instead of only 64 you are expecting.

What can you do?
As opposed to "standard" resnet, you removed stride from `conv1` and you do not have max pool after `conv1`. Moreover, you removed `layer4` which also have a stride. Therefore, You can add pooling to your net to reduce the spatial dimensions of `layer3`.
Alternatively, you can replace `nn.AvgPool(8)` with [`nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d([1, 1])`](https://pytorch.org/docs/0.4.1/nn.html#torch.nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d) an avg pool that outputs only one feature regardless of the spatial dimensions of the input feature map.